# How to insert updated records count, new records count and table name in audit table using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I am creating a SSIS package in which I have 15 Data flow tasks each for different table.In each data flow task I am inserting the records from source to destination and I am checking if record is available in destination I am updating that record if not inserting as new record.Now I want to store updated records count,new records count and table name in audit table

How can I do that easily?

Comment: Add Row Count component before the places where you'd like to know the count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In SSIS, how do I get the number of rows returned from the Source that SHOULD be processed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591985/in-ssis-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-returned-from-the-source-that-should-be)

Comment: I have used Row Count component at look up match output(RowsUpdated variable) and at look up no match(NewRows variable) and I am getting count without any issue. Now I want table name because I have column called TableName in my Audit table. I have 15 Data Flow Tasks in my package can I add one  Execute SQL Task  after each DFT to insert  row counts information and table name into Audit table